# Recommended type of  Read from file plist,string,rich text - objectiveC

Tags: objective-c, xcode

There are string,property list, rich text file to store values which among the three is better and having too much of plist in a project will it slow down the speed of app.

Property list is better for key-value pair storage ,In general which is most recommended?

Answer (score 1):

If you storing large amount of interrelated data you would go for core data or sqlite. 
If you have flat data there is nothing wrong in having normal text files.

All you have to remember is ,

- Disk I/O is slow. Too many read and write leads to bad performance.
- Primary memory is scarce. Use it judiciously.

Comment: thanks vignesh for your answer